# Yandex Metrika API: выгрузка визитов с фильтрацией по поисковым системам

Tags: yandex-metrika-api

Пытаюсь настроить запрос, чтобы получить кол-во визитов из конкретной поисковой системы, но каждый раз возвращается по нулям.
Вот запрос:

```
var url = `https://api-metrika.yandex.net/stat/v1/data?ids=${counterId}&metrics=ym:s:visits&dimensions=ym:s:date&filters=ym:s:lastsignTrafficSource=='organic' AND ym:s:searchEngine=='yandex'&date1=${startDate}&date2=${endDate}&accuracy=full`;
```

Пытался найти в доках метрики, к сожалению, там пусто. Саппорт молчит тоже.

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался:

```
 var url = `https://api-metrika.yandex.net/stat/v1/data?ids=${counterId}&metrics=ym:s:visits&dimensions=ym:s:date&filters=ym:s:lastsignSearchEngineRoot =='google' AND ym:s:lastsignTrafficSource=='organic'&date1=${startDate}&date2=${endDate}&accuracy=full`;
```